# Batch rename in hadoop

Tags: bash, hadoop, file-rename

How can I rename all files in a hdfs directory to have a `.lzo` extension? `.lzo.index` files should not be renamed.

For example, this directory listing:

> ```
> file0.lzo file0.lzo.index file0.lzo_copy_1
> ```

could be renamed to:

> ```
> file0.lzo file0.lzo.index file0.lzo_copy_1.lzo
> ```

These files are lzo compressed, and I need them to have the `.lzo` extension to be recognized by hadoop.

Comment: Using the Java API or command line tools?

Comment: command line tools would be best, thanks

Comment: @beefyhalo, we created a command line tool, you will find it in our answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you don't want to write Java Code for this - I think using the command line HDFS API is your best bet:

[`mv` in Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.0/hdfs_shell.html#mv)

`hadoop fs -mv URI [URI …] <dest>`

You can get the paths using a small one liner:

```
% hadoop fs -ls /user/foo/bar | awk  '!/^d/ {print $8}'

/user/foo/bar/blacklist
/user/foo/bar/books-eng
...
```

the `awk` will remove directories from output..now you can put these files into a variable:

```
% files=$(hadoop fs -ls /user/foo/bar | awk  '!/^d/ {print $8}')
```

and rename each file..

```
% for f in $files; do hadoop fs -mv $f $f.lzo; done
```

you can also use `awk` to filter the files for other criteria. This should remove files that match the regex `nolzo`. However it's untested. But this way you can write flexible filters.

```
% files=$(hadoop fs -ls /user/foo/bar | awk  '!/^d|nolzo/ {print $8}' )
```

test if it works with replacing the `hadoop` command with `echo`:

```
$ for f in $files; do echo $f $f.lzo; done
```

Edit: Updated examples to use `awk` instead of `sed` for more reliable output.

The "right" way to do it is probably using the [HDFS Java API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) .. However using the shell is probably faster and more flexible for most jobs.

Comment: this is definitely helpful, although your cut approach doesn't work predictably, and the sed gives me errors

Comment: Yes it's far from perfect. I guess using `awk` or coming up with something more sophisticated for parsing `hadoop fs -ls` should work through...

Comment: I updated the answer to use `awk`. Should work better now. Time to learn `awk` for me ;)

Comment: cool, it looks better with awk. I'm using this awk filter: `!/^d|\.lzo|\.index|\_SUCCESS/` and things are working nicely. Thx!

Comment: This works, but it's very slow if you are renaming thousands of files.

Comment: You can try to gain some speed by trying to execute the for loop in parallel using GNU parallel or something like that. Using the Java Hadoop-API is probably faster.

Comment: add a `| awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'` after the awk command above to strip out the leading directory names

Comment: @mt_ the first awk command is missing the closing single quote. Should be: files=$(hadoop fs -ls /user/foo/bar | awk  '!/^d/ {print $8}')

Comment: you  can add  speed  by  printing   "dfs -mv"  commands  into  a  file  and  then  execute  all commands  in one  hive  console session  with "hive -f".  You will save lots  of  time against  approach to   start  "hadoop  fs"  for each command  in your  list.

Answer (score 9):

When I had to rename many files I was searching for an efficient solution and stumbled over this question and [thi-duong-nguyen](/users/715283/thi-duong-nguyen)'s remark that renaming many files is very slow. I implemented a Java solution for batch rename operations which I can highly recommend, since it is *orders of magnitude* faster. The basic idea is to use `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem`'s `rename()` method:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://master:8020");
FileSystem dfs = FileSystem.get(conf);
dfs.rename(from, to);
```

where `from` and `to` are `org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path` objects. The easiest way is to create a list of files to be renamed (including their new name) and feed this list to the Java program.

I [have published](https://github.com/rjoberon/hadoop-tools#batchrename) the complete implementation which reads such a mapping from `STDIN`. It renamed 100 files in less than four seconds (the same time was required to rename 7000 files!) while the `hdfs dfs -mv` based approach described before requires 4 *minutes* to rename 100 files.

Comment: I'm facing this very issue, and it makes perfect sense that using a java approach like the one mentioned is so much faster - I imagine it's using a single connection vs creating and destroying a unique one for each file.
However, I'm wondering if anyone has been able to run this type of code on EMR.
I can't seem to get it to to work.
Based on what I'm seeing here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-script.html) I have to build the code ON the cluster.
But that seems pretty heavy-handed just to move some files.
Has anyone been able to run this on EMR?

Answer (score 2):

We created an utility to do bulk renaming of files in HDFS: https://github.com/tenaris/hdfs-rename. The tool is limited, but if you want you can contribute to improve it with recursive, awk regex syntax and so on.